# Maximum size of list in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Dear Netlogo community,

I was wondering about the size of list in Netlogo. Does anyone know about the maximum size of list can have in netlogo?

Answer (score 1):

You definitely won't be able to have more than 2147483647 elements (2^31 - 1); this limit comes from the underlying implementation (`scala.collection.immutable.Vector`).

You may run out of RAM first though; see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#howbig.